Postfix transport maps lookup failure
I started to get temporary errors when I am sending emails:

Sep 5 08:57:45 rb01-he postfix/trivial-rewrite[370959]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf lookup error for "igazgatas@domain.hu"
Sep 5 08:57:45 rb01-he postfix/trivial-rewrite[370959]: warning: transport_maps lookup failure
Sep 5 08:57:45 rb01-he postfix/smtps/smtpd[371389]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[84.206.73.101]: 451 4.3.0 <igazgatas@domain.hu>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<igazgatas@domain.hu> to=<penz?gy@domain.hu> proto=ESMTP helo=<KATO>

My postfix main.cf:
transport_maps = 
  hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman,
  proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf

This search in a mail_transport table which is completely empty.
My question is is it safe, can it prevent the lookup errors if I just modify my main.cf this line to:
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman

What do you think?
The transport_maps can be found here in my main.cf:
proxy_read_maps =
  $local_recipient_maps
  $mydestination
  $virtual_alias_maps
  $virtual_alias_domains
  $sender_bcc_maps
  $virtual_mailbox_maps
  $virtual_mailbox_domains
  $relay_recipient_maps
  $relay_domains
  $canonical_maps
  $sender_canonical_maps
  $recipient_canonical_maps
  $relocated_maps
  $transport_maps
  $mynetworks
  $smtpd_sender_login_maps
  $virtual_uid_maps
  $virtual_gid_maps
  $smtpd_client_restrictions
  $smtpd_sender_restrictions
  $smtpd_recipient_restrictions
  $smtp_sasl_password_maps
  $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps

